# Is there a way to detect from userAgent if cache is disabled in browser?

Tags: javascript, user-agent

Is there a way to detect (in javascript) if the user has configured their browser to disable (browser) caching?  ie. If this checkbox (in Chrome) is checked:

[image]

Comment: I've never seen anything cache-related in a user agent. Why would the server need to know this?

Comment: @Barmar The server doesn't need to know this (hence why I asked how this can be accomplished in javascript). I want to be able to display a dialog if the user has caching disabled.

Comment: Why does it have to be in the userAgent? You just want to know if there's a way for JavaScript to find out if caching is enabled.

Comment: @Barmar Correct. I suppose I had assumed through userAgent was the only way.

Comment: That's the textbook definition of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Barmar That's fair.  The "already answered" solution is kinda gross.

Comment: There's no real API for this, so the best you can do is heuristics like that.